# Recreating a ggplot2 geom_point() using base graphics

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've the following ggplot2 code and I'd like to use base graphics instead of ggplot2 to generate a similiar output - but I can't seem to find a way to differentiate more than one "attribute" with the normal plot. Am I missing something:

Ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data.df, aes(x=Axis1, y=Axis2, shape=Plant, color=Type)) +
geom_point()
```

My plot attempt (the inline help got me quite some way):

```
data.ma <- as.matrix(data.df)

plot(range(data.ma[,6]), range(data.ma[,7]),xlab="Axis 1",ylab="Axis 2")
points(data.ma[data.ma[,1] == 'Plant1',6],
   data.ma[data.ma[,1] == 'Plant1',7], pch=2)
points(data.ma[data.ma[,1] == 'Plant2',6],
   data.ma[data.ma[,1] == 'Plant2',7], pch=3)
legend(0,legend=c("Plant1","Plant2"))
```

This gives me a plot where at least the "Plant" type can be distinguished in the plot, but it does seem far to complicated and I can't figure out how to change the color of all points depending on the "Type" row.

Any suggestions?

Edit - an example with data // where I realize that my first attempt with plot doesn't even give a correct example :( :

```
library(ggplot2)
data.df <- data.frame(
  Plant=c('Plant1','Plant1','Plant1','Plant2','Plant2','Plant2'),
  Type=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
  Axis1=c(0.2,-0.4,0.8,-0.2,-0.7,0.1),
  Axis2=c(0.5,0.3,-0.1,-0.3,-0.1,-0.8)
)


ggplot(data.df, aes(x=Axis1, y=Axis2, shape=Plant, color=Type)) +
geom_point()

data.ma <- as.matrix(data.df)
plot(range(data.ma[,3]), range(data.ma[,4]),xlab="Axis 1",ylab="Axis 2")
points(data.ma[data.ma[,1] == 'Plant1',3],
       data.ma[data.ma[,1] == 'Plant1',4], pch=2)
points(data.ma[data.ma[,1] == 'Plant2',3],
       data.ma[data.ma[,1] == 'Plant2',4], pch=3)
legend(0,legend=c("Plant1","Plant2"))
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use `ggplot2`? More specifically, would you consider `lattice` plots?

Comment: actually I usually only use ggplot2 plots --- but I offered to help a friend and her plots are done with the "normal" plot so far and actually I'm a bit curious if it's really that hard ;)

Comment: Can you post something reproducible - i.e. based on an inbuilt dataset? Difficult to help otherwise.

Comment: Would you consider `lattice` plots?

Comment: @Andrie I never used lattice plots so far - ggplot2 helped me with everything so far - the answer for lattice should maybe part of another question?

Comment: OK, fair enough, and good luck with that. `lattice` was designed to make this problem a lot easier than base graphics. (And just to be clear - `lattice` forms part of base R, it's just an alternative graphics system.)

Comment: @Andrie - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679314 ;) I'm eager to learn this stuff and others will also find it useful - so thanks in advance

Comment: why can't you use `ggplot2` and something like `theme_bw()` to make it "look" more like base? e.g. `ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, z=letters[1:2]), aes(x, y, color=z))+geom_point()+theme_bw()` Both `lattice` and `ggplot2` were created since doing some of this more complicated plotting is so difficult in the base `plot`.

Comment: @Justin --- huh thanks - wasn't aware of that solution :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base plot and your data set:

```
with(data.df, 
     plot(x = Axis1, 
          y = Axis2, 
          col = factor(Type),                 
          pch = as.integer(factor(Plant))))
```

Does that do what you're looking for?  I'll leave the legend as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 4):

I was just about to post this and then I saw Justin beat to much of it. In any case, this includes some rudimentary legends:

```
color_foo <- colorRampPalette(c('lightblue','darkblue'))
colors <- color_foo(3)

plot(range(data.df[,3]), range(data.df[,4]),
        xlab="Axis 1",ylab="Axis 2",type = "n")
points(data.df$Axis1,data.df$Axis2,
        pch=c(3,4)[data.df$Plant],
        col = colors[data.df$Type])
legend("topright",legend=c("Plant1","Plant2"),pch = 3:4)
legend("bottomright",legend=c("Type1","Type2","Type3"),
        pch = 20,col = colors)
```

[image]